# How do I match only dotfiles in bash?

Tags: bash, wildcards, dot-files

`rm -rf .*` will only not end horribly because `rm` refuses to delete `.` and `..`.

How do I exclude these special directories from a glob pattern?

This is not solved by `dotglob` since I want to match only files beginning with a dot not all files.

Comment: History: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90075/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller, doesn't that one ask for all files, which is easily accomplished with `dotglob`? Here, they just want those starting with a dot.

Comment: Stéphane’s answer in it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264571/117549

Comment: Good catch @JeffSchaller but I suggest we repost the solution here so it will be found more easily. Would you do the honors?

Comment: The “duplicate” feature is exactly to put good solutions in *one* place...

Comment: I think I misread anyway. Which one of Stéphane's suggestions do you think should work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With bash, setting the `GLOBIGNORE` special variable is some non-empty value is enough to make it ignore `.` and `..` when expanding globs. From [the Bash docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion):

> The `GLOBIGNORE` shell variable may be used to restrict the set of
>   filenames matching a pattern. If `GLOBIGNORE` is set, each matching
>   filename that also matches one of the patterns in `GLOBIGNORE` is
>   removed from the list of matches. If the `nocaseglob` option is set,
>   the matching against the patterns in `GLOBIGNORE` is performed without
>   regard to case. The filenames `.` and `..` are always ignored when
>   `GLOBIGNORE` is set and not null. However, setting `GLOBIGNORE` to a
>   non-null value has the effect of enabling the dotglob shell option, so
>   all other filenames beginning with a `‘.`’ will match.

If we set it to `.:..`, both `.` and `..` will be ignored. Since setting it to anything non-null will also get this behaviour, we might as well set it to just `.`

So:

```
GLOBIGNORE=.
rm -rf .*
```

(From [my earlier answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1078486/158442).)

Comment: I think this is the best way to solve the problem I was having since it specifically excludes the special cases.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
rm -rf .[^.] .??*
```

This command can catch all cases.

`.[^.]` will catch any two character entries. 
`.??*` will only match 3+ character filenames.

Answer (score 3):

@Goro has, I think, the simplest totally correct answer. However, I find it's a pain to type. I would suggest instead

```
ls .??*
```

It's absolutely true that this will miss files like `.a`, but those are so extraordinarily rare that in practice I don't think it matters, especially for interactive usage.

Comment: This is genius! :). It's just what I wanted, short, simple and it works! None of my dot files have just a single character after the dot (all of them have longer names) so this works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude single and double dots:

```
rm -rf {..?,.[!.]}*
```

- `..?*` matches everything with two dots followed by anything
- `.[!.]*` matches everything with single dot not followed by another dot

Answer (score 1):

With `extglob`:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ touch ... .a .bbb ..c foo
$ echo .!(.|)
... .a .bbb ..c
```

`!(.|)` matches anything but a dot or empty, so `.!(.|)` matches anything starting with a dot, except `.` and `..`.

Answer (score 1):

With `find`, it's a bit more to type but you can be more explicit, which makes it easier to understand:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' ! -name . ! -name .. -exec rm -rf {} +
```

This calls `rm -rf` with all names in the current directory (only) that starts with a dot and which is not `.` nor `..`.  I'm not using `-delete` here as that predicate may not delete non-empty directories.

If you want to match only regular files in the current directory, it becomes even easier:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.*' -delete
```

Here, we don't need to exclude `.` or `..` as they are automatically excluded by `-type f`.

Change `-type f` to `! -type d` to make it delete any non-directory (i.e. symbolic links etc.)